# Android Creating a custom config file

Tags: android

I would like to ask which would be better to put config files in Android, since Android doesn't support subfolders under values.

Example:

```
values/
     config/
         api.xml
```

What is the preferred style?

1. Creating a class with static variable:

   ```
   package myapp.config;

   public static class Api{
       public static String CLIENT_ID = "1234567890";
       public static String CLIENT_SECRET = "123456789";
   }
   ```
2. Add everything in `string.xml`:

   ```
      <string name="config_api_client_id">1234567890</string>
      <string name="config_client_secret">123456789</string>
   ```

Comment: Use the `SharedPreferences`, to store your configurations.

Comment: I think that's dangerous. what if user clear the app data?

Comment: What if your user resets the device to the factory state?

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer class with final static variables. It is as constant as using string.xml, but when you use string resources (string.xml), you need a `Context` object to get the strings.

When changing your code snippet to the snippet below, you can access the variables from each and every piece of code and you know that the value of the variables never change.

```
public class Api{

    public final static String CLIENT_ID = "1234567890";
    public final static String CLIENT_SECRET = "123456789";

}
```

Then you can access the variables like so `Api.CLIENT_ID`